# Create custom keyboard in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-2.x

I need to create custom keyboard with some sort of button animation, is it possible to do with cocos2d-x? I know that there are exists two text fields: RichText and TextField. TextField connected to native mobile device keyboard. Is it possible to send to TextField same events as native keyboard do? And if yes, than how to edit inserted text?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can easily set text of your TextField with:-

```
void setText(const char* text);
```

Function of "TextField" class of cocos2d-x.
Just explore "UITextField" class of cocos2d-x

Comment: I tried, but there no way to edit that text, I mean like on native platform, when you put your finger and hold about 2 seconds, than cursor appears and you can move through the string back and forward. I also found EditBox element, but I works with bugs on Android (after cursor for moving inside field appears something goes wrong so the keyboard hides and screen jumps up and down). I tried to find commercial one but I didn't find any. I found that it's possible to create my own implementation of EditBox with custom keyboard. Will try ))